# Plot doesn't show in if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, if-statement, plot

Im trying to create 2 different plots by specific conditions.
the condition in get from text that i upload that define how to filter the data. There are 2 options to filter it: by age or by gender. Each graph should be save when the if statement is true.

This is the code:

```
    idc_list = list(conditions[4].split(","))
    new_data = df[df['ICD9_code'].isin(idc_list)]
    print(new_data.head)

    if conditions[2] == 1:
      new_data = new_data[['age','Death']]
      ranges = [0,30,60,90,120]
      group = new_data.groupby(pd.cut(new_data.age, ranges)).Death.agg('count')
      group.plot(x='age', y='Death', kind='bar')
      plt.title("Death vs Age")
      plt.xlabel('Age',fontsize=10)
      plt.ylabel('Numbers of Death',fontsize=10)
      plt.show()
      plt.savefig(plt.savefig('{}.png'.format("Result")))


   if conditions[3] == 1:
     new_data = new_data[['gender_x', 'Death']]
     group = df.groupby('gender_x').Death.agg('count')
     group.plot(x='gender_x', y='Death', kind='bar')
     plt.title("Death vs Gender")
     plt.xlabel('Gender',fontsize=10)
     plt.ylabel('Numbers of Death',fontsize=10)
     plt.show()
     plt.savefig("Results_Gender")
```

I want to create 2 different plots to each condition and save it.
When i run it , it doesn't show the plot and doesn't save it.
How can I solve it? I couldn't succeed to save the plot for some reason.

Comment: Hi! Are you sure that `conditions[2]` and `conditions[3]` are satisfied (true)?
Moreover, when you want to save a figure you should specify the file format (e.g. `.png` or `.pdf`)

Comment: One of them is always true. i also tried to specify the format ant it didn't worked.

Comment: Ok I see. Can you try to remove `plt.show()` and keep only `savefig`?
I guess you are running the script from bash? or jupyter?

Comment: It is still doesn't work. it doesn't save it. i use Pycharm.